# Asynchronous Download of Files

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-asyncio

This downloads updated fasta files (protein sequences) from a database, I've gotten this to work faster using `asyncio` compared to `requests`, however I'm not convinced the downloads are actually happening asynchronously.

```
import os
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
import asyncio

folder = '~/base/fastas/proteomes/'

upos = {'UP000005640': 'Human_Homo_sapien',
        'UP000002254': 'Dog_Boxer_Canis_Lupus_familiaris',
        'UP000002311': 'Yeast_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae',
        'UP000000589': 'Mouse_Mus_musculus',
        'UP000006718': 'Monkey_Rhesus_macaque_Macaca_mulatta',
        'UP000009130': 'Monkey_Cynomolgus_Macaca_fascicularis',
        'UP000002494': 'Rat_Rattus_norvegicus',
        'UP000000625': 'Escherichia_coli',
        }

#https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=proteome:UP000005640&format=fasta Example link
startline = r'https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=proteome:'
endline = r'&format=fasta&include=False' #include is true to include isoforms, make false for only canonical sequences

async def fetch(session, link, folderlocation, name):
    async with session.get(link, timeout=0) as response:
        try:
            file = await aiofiles.open(folderlocation, mode='w')
            file.write(await response.text())
            await file.close()
            print(name, 'ended')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            loc = ''.join((r'/'.join((folderlocation.split('/')[:-1])), '/'))
            command = ' '.join(('mkdir -p', loc))
            os.system(command)
            file = await aiofiles.open(folderlocation, mode='w')
            file.write(await response.text())
            await file.close()
            print(name, 'ended')

async def rfunc():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for upo, name in upos.items():
            print(name, 'started')
            link = ''.join((startline, upo, endline))
            folderlocation =''.join((folder, name, '.fasta'))
            await fetch(session, link, folderlocation, name)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(rfunc())
```

My output from running this:

```
In [5]: runfile('~/base/Fasta Proteome Updater.py')
Human_Homo_sapien started
Human_Homo_sapien ended
Dog_Boxer_Canis_Lupus_familiaris started
Dog_Boxer_Canis_Lupus_familiaris ended
Yeast_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae started
Yeast_Saccharomyces_cerevisiae ended
Mouse_Mus_musculus started
Mouse_Mus_musculus ended
Monkey_Rhesus_macaque_Macaca_mulatta started
Monkey_Rhesus_macaque_Macaca_mulatta ended
Monkey_Cynomolgus_Macaca_fascicularis started
Monkey_Cynomolgus_Macaca_fascicularis ended
Rat_Rattus_norvegicus started
Rat_Rattus_norvegicus ended
Escherichia_coli started
Escherichia_coli ended
```

The printed output seems to signify the downloads are happening one at a time, is there something wrong here?

Comment: I don’t know the answer but can I make a suggestion where you add a finally clause to your exception handling and put ‘file = await aiofiles.open(folderlocation, mode='w')
            file.write(await response.text())
            await file.close()
            print(name, 'ended')’ inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping the items to download and waiting (`await`) for each item to finish. To make them happen all at one time, you need to schedule all downloads for execution at once - e.g. using [gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently).

Then your code could look like this:

```
async def rfunc():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await gather(
            *[
                 fetch(
                     session,
                     ''.join((startline, upo, endline)),
                     ''.join((folder, name, '.fasta')),
                     name,
                 ) for upo, name in upos.items()
             ]
        )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(rfunc())
```